# change fetched json data in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am new to node js 
I had fetched content from database `Data`.
`Data` consist of `_id`, `likechecked` from this id I want to check with `Like` if the `_id` exist means I want to change the value of `likechecked` as `1` or else `0`

Now my problem after fetching data  from `Data` I had itrete the fetched data for checking with `Like` 
After checking Like I can't change the value of `likechecked`

```
Data.find().then(data => {
            const user_id = "balaji@007"
            for (var _id in data) {
                Like.findOne({ postid: data[_id]._id,userid:user_id }).then(data2 => {
                    if(data2 != null){
                        data[_id].likechecked= 0
                    }else{
                        console.log("s")
                        data[_id].likechecked= 1
                    }
                console.log(data)
                });
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
```

Comment: try changing that var _id to let _id. because let is scoped only to that block.

Comment: @learner Thanks for asking your question! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you post the JSON object that you're trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to save the whole document after changing it's values.

```
data.save().then(() => console.log('saved')
```